# Flutter itemScrollController at start app directly jump to index without pushing buttons

Tags: flutter

How can I prepare `ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItemScrollController();` when the app are starting, it jumps directly to the index?

I am using the ScrollablePositionedList: https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Comment: use `initState`

Comment: See 
[initialScrollIndex property](https://pub.dev/documentation/scrollable_positioned_list/latest/scrollable_positioned_list/ScrollablePositionedList/initialScrollIndex.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
@override
void initState() {
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   // executes after build
   _scrollController.jumpTo(index: YOUR_INDEX);
   });
   super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pratik. That's what I am looking for. I tried without WidgetsBinding and get then an error.